# @font-face doesn't display in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I've been trying to use @font-face on a site, I use the css that font squirrel gives me and it looks good in Safari, IE and on the iphone but in firefox it don´t show up.
I have Firefox 7.0.1 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard.
I've searched the web and tried some of the "solutions" but none has worked.
the site I wanna load this @font-face is http://www.utochinredning.se

Can some one point me in some direction of what might be a solution?

Comment: Works for me in FF 6.0 MAC. FF 7.0 works fine, too.

Comment: you may need to check your settings in about:config  i know in lion they are turned off by default

Answer (score 0):

Post your code?

Shot in the dark, but have you included all the appropriate font files? This is a sample of what your @font-face should look like (at least what mine looks like)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Museo300';
    src: url('Museo300-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Museo300-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Museo300-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Museo300-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Museo300-Regular-webfont.svg#Museo300') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have the following font files:

```
Museo300-Regular-webfont.eot
Museo300-Regular-webfont.svg
Museo300-Regular-webfont.ttf
Museo300-Regular-webfont.woff
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Museo300";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```